# Why ASUS Q500A fails to dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I have followed several links including Ubuntu's guide to UEFI Installation and several guides on AskUbuntu but I have a unique problem:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133526&page=1

http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/

After installation Live USB restarts rather than booting into Ubuntu, unlike most problems, Windows is functional (but lets get beyond W8)

There are two guides, one that encourages CSM to be enabled and disabled (AskUbuntu and Ubuntu Forums) When it is disabled the launcher shows, but then just a blank screen appears. "blank screen" solutions to use nomodeset (via initial boot command)

This ASUS Q500A is missing efi/boot/bootx64.efi when I try to Launch EFI Shell in the "BIOS" it fails. Any thoughts on why would this ASUS model fail all the manuals?

Comment: Please provide the links that you followed.

Comment: Can you also provide a [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) report, and the output of 'sudo efibootmgr'? Since it restarts into Live USB maybe the grub entry points to the USB device instead of your root partition on the HDD. Otherwise, people are [reporting in forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138407) that dual booting works on this model.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think launch csm should be disabled because this is legacy mode.
If you disable launch csm and it still wont boot, set up a live disk using startup disk creator, or unetbootin. From the live disk install linux boot-repair. (just google it) Run it and do the recommended procedures. Please let me know where you are at with this problem!

Comment: please summarize the steps you took to provide a complete answer rather than simply posting a link.

Comment: @hydroxide used the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility from a Live CD.  It worked for me, too.